# Why does the scp command not work?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to scp a file from my virtual machine to my host. It seems to be working on the command line but the file has not been moved to my host machine at all and I'm not sure why this is. Here is the command that I use to scp the file.

```
scp drubio@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/var/local/config/openhub.yml /home/drubio/desktop
```

When I execute the code, I have this output from the terminal.

```
openhub.yml     100%  878     0.9KB/s   00:00
```

However, when I look on my desktop, the file isn't there!

I've followed the recommendations from a previous question I asked scping, a file from host to remote. The only thing I'm trying to do is the reverse. [Scp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531564/is-this-the-correct-syntax-to-scp-a-downloaded-file-into-ubuntu)

Help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not really a programming question (try SuperUser, ServerFault, or the Ubuntu site for this kind of thing...)  Although if it's a case-sensitive file system, I'd ask if your "Desktop" directory is actually capitalized, and you've downloaded a file called "desktop" with lowercase into your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Dan: it looks like you're copying the file openhub.yml to your home folder with the name desktop.

Mind the case:

scp drubio@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/var/local/config/openhub.yml /home/drubio/Desktop

Comment: Thanks Seba. I thought the case wouldn't make a difference. I ran a pwd on my terminal and the result returns /Users/drubio/desktop. I tried changing the cases but to no avail. It still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @DanRubio: All that means is that you're in a directory named `desktop`. Whether the contents of that directory show up on your desktop is up to your GUI environment. What does `echo $HOME` print? Under Ubuntu, your home directory is normally under `/home`, not `/Users`; did you configure it differently for some resaon? If you create a file in that directory (without using `scp`), does it appear on your desktop?